# Правописание Н и НН в кратких прилагательных и причастиях

Tags: орфография

Объясните мне пожалуйста. Глагол несовершенного вида "красить" 
НекрашеНая крыша (прилагательное) - Крыша совершенно не крашена (совершенно - пояснительное слово, значит "не крашена"- причастие). Крыша не крашена (пояснительных слов нет, но все равно остается краткое причастие). Вопрос: От глаголов несовершенного вида образуются только краткие причастия и не могут краткие прилагательные, поэтому  "НЕ" всегда пишется раздельно, и в самом кратком причастии во всех случаях пишется только одно "Н ?

"Воспитать" - глагол совершенного вида.  Воспитанная девушка - девушка воспитаННа (краткое прилагательное) / Девушка воспитаНа мамой (есть зависимое слово, значит краткое причастие, пишется с одним "Н"). "Покрасить" - глагол совершенного вида.  ПокрашеННая крыша - Крыша покрашеНа   (зависимых слов нет, значит краткое прилагательное. Крыша вовсе не покрашеНа (зависимое слово есть, значит одно "Н"). Получается: девушка воспитаННа, а крыша покрашеНа, так или не так?

Объясните мне поподробнее, своими словами, когда именно в кратких прилагательных, образованных от глаголов совершенного вида пишется одно "Н", а когда два "НН". Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

А. "От глаголов несовершенного вида образуются только краткие причастия и не могут краткие прилагательные" - **некорректная фраза**. От глаголов сначала образуются полные формы причастий и отглагольных прилагательных, а затем от полных форм образуются краткие формы.

Схема образования полной формы: Красить - крашеный (прилаг.) - некрашеный (прил.)

От бесприставочных глаголов несовершенного вида образуются отглагольные ПРИЛАГАТЕЛЬНЫЕ (Н), так как обозначается не  процессуальный признак, связанный со значением времени, а постоянный качественный признак. Некрашеный - также прилагательное, обозначающее качественный признак.

Схема образования краткой формы: Крашеный - крашена (прич.), некрашеный - не крашена  (прич.)

При образовании краткой формы отглагольное прилагательное ПЕРЕХОДИТ в причастие, так как краткая форма обычно является в предложении сказуемым  (то есть краткие отглагольные формы обозначают признак по действию).

Б. Существуют небольшое количество ПАРНЫХ вариантов вида  "причастие - отпричастное прилагательное": образованный, воспитанный и др., в этом случае отпричастное прилагательное полностью утрачивает значение процессуального признака и даже в краткой форме обозначает только качественный признак (НН).

Воспитать - воспитанный (прич.) - воспитанный (отпричастное прилаг.)

Воспитанный (прич.) - воспитана

воспитанный (отприч. прил.) - воспитанна.

Девушка воспитана родителями (кр. прич., признак по действию). Она умна и воспитанна (отприч. прилаг., качественный признак)

Answer (score 1):

Разберемся. В примерах ***"Крыша совершенно не крашена", "Крыша некрашена"*** пояснительное слово ***"совершенно"*** не влияет на написание  суффикса причастий - н, нн. Разграничение кратких причастий и прилагательных в некоторых случаях осуществляется не только по наличию или отсутствию приставок, зависимых слов, но и по смыслу.При причастиях обычно имеется или мыслится существительное в творительном падеже. В примерах "Крыша совершенно некрашена", - ***налицо постоянный признак***. Здесь нельзя по смыслу подставить ***существительное в творительном падеже.*** Это прилагательное.  "Крыша не крашена"(никем).Зависимое слово хоть и отсутствует, но по смыслу мыслится существительное в творительном падеже.Здесь на лицо временной признак. Стоит также отметить, что в кратких прилагательных пишется столько ***н,*** сколько было в полной форме. В слове "крашеный"одно н, поэтому и в краткой форме одно н. От глаголов совершенного вида так же образуются краткие прилагательные с качественным значением. Такие прилагательные имеют сравнительную степень. Воспитать - воспитанна(краткое прилагательное).

В примере ***"Девушка воспитаНа мамой"*** - действует вышеизложенное правило. ***В примерах "Крыша покрашеНа",  "Крыша вовсе не покрашеНа"*** - покрашена - краткое причастие. Здесь также действует вышеизложенное правило.

Comment: Серж, в кратких ПРИЛАГАТЕЛЬНЫХ, а не страдательных причастиях пишется столько н, сколько было в полной форме.

Comment: Да, Людмила, конечно! Вы правы! Спасибо за замечание. В уме одно, а пишу - другое!

Answer (score 1):

```
   От глаголов несовершенного вида образуются только краткие причастия и 
  не  могут краткие прилагательные, поэтому "НЕ" всегда 
    пишется  раздельно, и в самом кратком причастии во 
    всех   случаях    пишется только одно "Н ?
```

В прошедшем времени да, а в настоящем краткая форма возможна и от прилагательного и тогда с НЕ пишется слитно: неподражаемый-неподражаема, необходимый-необходима, невредимый-невредима.

НекрашеНая крыша -прилагательное, как и крашеный пол, неглаженый костюм.

Крыша совершенно не крашена -некорректное сочетание.(совершенно - пояснительное слово в значении "очень",применяется как раз с прилагательным (совершенно неинтересен, очень неинтересен) а крыша не может быть очень некрашеной - или крашеная, или некрашеная.

Можно сказать " Крыша ещё не крашена", "никем не крашена" - краткое причастие, её красили. И без зависимых слов тоже пишется раздельно и всегда с одной -Н-, потому что, как Вы верно сказали, НЕ с краткими причастиями всегда пишется раздельно. От прилагательных краткая форма может образовываться только от КАЧЕСТВЕННЫХ.

Воспитанная девушка - девушка воспитаННа (т.е.культурна, краткое прилагательное) / Девушка воспитаНа мамой (есть зависимое слово, значит краткое причастие, пишется с одним "Н"). Верно.

Сестра(какова?)тактична и сдержанна(её никто не сдерживал, она такая по характеру) - прилагательное,она несдержанна(вспыльчива)-прилагательное, в полной форме две -НН-, значит, и в краткой две.Атаки(что сделаны?) сдержаны-их сдержали, это краткое причастие - раздельно и одна -Н-.

ПокрашеННая крыша - причастие: та, которую покрасили.
Крыша покрашеНа -та, которую покрасили, краткое причастие. Крыша вовсе не покрашеНа -краткое причастие.